# Slick Carousel arrow not working when Smooth Scrolling enabled instead of snapping to images

Tags: jquery, reactjs, slider, carousel, slick.js

This is the code that enabled smooth scrolling but arrows are not working

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.aboutHome__imageSlider')
    .not('.slick-initialized')
    .slick({
      speed: 10000,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 0,
      arrows: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      infinite: true,
      prevArrow: '.arrow_prev9',
      nextArrow: '.arrow_next9',
      cssEase: 'linear',
      pauseOnFocus: false,
      pauseOnHover: false,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1024,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            arrows: false,
          },
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 750,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            arrows: false,
          },
        },
      ],
    });
});
```

Comment: Why did you add a react tag? And please add more infos around ` arrows are not working` and show us a reduced example we can debug

Comment: I am using slick slider on react. I am looking for slider with smooth scrolling between slides and not stopping per slide. So, I used slick carousel but button are not working when autoplayspeed is 0. Any kind of help would be great or suggestion for the slider with the smooth sliding carousel. And I'm new to react.